# Can I make a client socket only to establish a connection using python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading about socket module in a web learning site about python, they gave us a simple steps to use socket module like follows:

```
import socket

with socket.socket() as client_socket:

    hostname = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 9090

    address = (hostname, port)
    client_socket.connect(address)

    data = 'Wake up, Neo'
    data = data.encode()

    client_socket.send(data)
    response = client_socket.recv(1024)

    response = response.decode()
    print(response)
```

when executing I got the error message:
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

when I searched about this some sites was talking about server listening and I see in most of tutorials about server socket and they use it along with client one.

so Is the error message related to the fact that I'm not using a server socket and is it a must to use them both

Update:

after reading the answers I got, I went to the test.py file that the course instructors use to evaluate our codes and I see that they make the server socket in it , so the server is already made by them. that take me back to the Error I got why does it happen then.

```
def server(self):
        '''function - creating a server and answering clients'''
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('localhost', 9090))
        self.ready = True
        try:
            self.sock.listen(1)
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            self.connected = True
            conn.settimeout(15)
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                self.message.append(data.decode('utf8'))
                if len(self.message) > 1_000_000:
                    conn.send(
                        json.dumps({
                            'result': 'Too many attempts to connect!'
                        }).encode('utf8'))
                    break
                if not data:
                    break
```

Comment: YES, you can do it

Comment: This is the client part of the connection. to establish a connection you need a server as well. The server needs to be listening at the address: `localhost:9090`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each connection requires a client, which initiates the connection, and a server, which listens for the incoming connection from the client. The code you have shown is for the client end of the connection. In order for this to run successfully you will need a server listening for the connection you are trying to create.

In the code you showed us you have the lines

```
hostname = '127.0.0.1'
port = 9090

address = (hostname, port)
client_socket.connect(address)
```

These are the lines that define what server you are connecting to. In this case it is a server at `127.0.0.1` (which is localhost, the same machine you are running the code on) listening on port `9090`.

If you want to make your own server then you can look at the [documentation for Python sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and the particular functions you want to know about are `bind`, `listen`, and `accept`. You can find examples [at the bottom of that same page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example).

Given that you appear to have found this code as part of a course, I suspect they may provide you with matching server code at some point in order to be able to use this example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this is the only code they gave to make a socket,  I checked the coming lessons and not a word about server sock. and from examples you provide I see that I need to make 2 files and run them both to establish the socket. @Kemp